# Merge Flux result and return Flux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a `List<Event>` and for each `Event`, I need to set `EventDocument`. I get `Flux<EventDocument>`from an api. I need to map correct `EventDocument` to `Event` and return `Flux<Event>`.

Api call to get `EventDocument`

```
private Flux<EventDocument> getDocuments(List<Long> eventIds) {
    String url = this.documentServiceUrl + "/events?eventId=" + eventIds;
    return getWebClient()
            .post()
            .uri(url)
            .body(eventIds, List.class)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(EventDocument.class)
            .log()
            .onErrorResume(error -> Flux.empty());
}
```

How do I map results from above to correct `Event` and return `Flux<Event>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
Flux<EventDocument> eventDocuments = ...;
Flux<Event> events = eventDocuments.map(mapToEventFunction);
```